# How to open/import Netbeans HTML5 project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, netbeans, ide

I have a HTML5 project created in Netbeans (Angular JS, CSS, HTML)

[image]

How can I import this project into Eclipse?

I tried "File -> Import -> Choose General -> Existing Projects into Workspace" But because this is not a standard Java project (Maven, Ant etc.), Eclipse does not recognize it. Is there a way to still import this? I tried "Import File System" but the IDE asks for Import "Into Folder". I don't want Eclipse to copy over my sources.